# how to autowire bean in the servlet filters in spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-boot, autowired

I have a `spring-boot` application.

I have no `ApplicationContext.xml` or `web.xml` files in my project. I prefer to avoid them and have everything configured in Java code.

I have read the following the posts about bean injection in servlet filters.

1. [How can I get a Spring bean in a servlet filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882042/how-can-i-get-a-spring-bean-in-a-servlet-filter)
2. http://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-05-04-dependency-injection-into-filters-using-delegatingfilterproxy/
3. [spring injection in servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765992/spring-injection-in-servlet-filter)

After reading them, I started to use `DelegatingFilterProxy`.

My question is how to `autowire` the bean into filter and avoid using `xml` files especially for DelegatingFilterProxy configuration.

The code snipped is available from the second post hosted in [github.](https://github.com/DeadCodeRising/inject-dependencies-into-your-filters)

```
public class AuditHandler {

    public void auditRequest(String appName, ServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(appName + ": Received request from " + request.getRemoteAddr() );
    }
}

public class AuditFilter implements Filter {

    private final AuditHandler auditHandler;
    private String appName;

    public AuditFilter(AuditHandler auditHandler) {
        this.auditHandler = auditHandler;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        auditHandler.auditRequest(appName, request);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        appName = filterConfig.getInitParameter("appName");
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}

ApplicationContext.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="auditHandler" class="com.deadcoderising.AuditHandler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="auditFilter" class="com.deadcoderising.AuditFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="auditHandler"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

web.xml

<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="true">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>auditFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>appName</param-name>
            <param-value>di-example</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>auditFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add a `FilterRegistrationBean` to your main Application class (class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) and let Spring provide instance of the `AuditHandler`:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public FilterRegistrationBean auditFilterRegistration(AuditHandler handler) {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new AuditFilter(handler));
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(3); // ordering in the filter chain
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

If this doesn't work (e.g. your `AuditHandler` implementation is not annotated properly or it's not on the default package scanning path) you can instruct Spring to provide it (also in your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class):

```
@Bean
public AuditHandler auditHandler() {
    return new AuditHandlerImplementation();
}
```

Comment: if I have a number of filters to be applied, how is the order specified?

Comment: `FilterRegistrationBean#setOrder(int)`, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will test this now

Comment: how can I do the same in non-spring boot application. There is no `FilterRegistrationBean` available in spring MVC

Comment: The filter can also be registered in the same way in a configuration class (class annotated with `@Configuration`)

Comment: @mzc how register multiple filters on different URLs? If set() sets one.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into the ***init*** method of your ***filter class***.

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

So the init method will look like:

```
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        appName = filterConfig.getInitParameter("appName");
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }
```

Now, you can use `@Autowired` or `@Inject` or `@Resource` anotation to inject the dependency (bean) into the filter class.